# How to compute Coulomb scattering rate(in early universe)?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, electrons, astrophysics, plasma-physics

I want to compare Coulomb scattering rate with Hubble's expansion rate.

To compute Coulomb scattering rate, I know that

$$ \Gamma = n_p\sigma v_{rel} $$

Here, $\sigma = \frac{e^{4}}{(4\pi\epsilon_o)^{2}}\frac{1}{m_e^{2}v_{rel}^{4}}4\pi(1+\frac{m_e}{m_p}) ln\Lambda$

I can approximate all the terms here. But I do not know what should I substitute for $v_{rel}$ given that I am dealing with early universe.

Failed attempts- I thought I can substitute $$ v_{rel} = |v_{p,rms}-v_{e,rems}| \approx v_{e,rms}$$ Since, $m_p \gg m_e$

Here, I can get rems values by using the fact that electron and photons are tightly coupled until Decoupling and hence $$ T_e = T_\gamma = T_o*z $$ where, $T_o = 2.7^{o}C$ is the CMB temperature today and $Z$ is the redshift.

However I noticed that with smaller redshifts a.k.a later times temperature $T$ will fall and hence $v_{rel}$ will fall. But I see that $$\Gamma \propto \frac{1}{v_{rel}^{3}}$$
Thus interaction rate increases with time. ***This makes no sense at all***.

So, what should $v_{rel}$ be taken as? In online PDF's I noticed that they take it as a constant along with masses during analysis. How?

**NOTE- After discussing with my professor and studying a bit more I came to know that this is actually a feature of Coloumb interaction. Its coupling increases actually increases over time. So the question is answered.**

Comment: I think you have something wrong here.  The Coulomb collision rate is proportional to $v^{-3}$.  If you use the thermal speed for $v$ here, then as the universe cools, the collision rate will fall.

Comment: @honeste_vivere If universe cools, $v$ falls and hence $\Gamma$ increases. Am I missing some silly detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the standard [Coulomb collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision) rates in numerous places.  For example, a recent paper by [*Wilson et al.* [2018]](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4365/aab71c/) has some convenient formulas and numerical results for the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind).

> Thus interaction rate increases with time. ***This makes no sense at all.***

Let's ignore the extra factors and just assume the collision rate, $\nu$, goes as $\nu \propto n \ v^{-3}$ or if we replace the speeds with thermal speeds, then $\nu \propto n \ T^{-3/2}$.  At the time of the [Big Bang nucleosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe), the temperature was ~$10^{9}$ K (or ~86200 eV) and the mass density was ~0.004 kg m<sup>-3</sup>.  If we assume all protons, then the corresponding number density is $n_{p} \sim 10^{24}$ m<sup>-3</sup> (**Note that even if we start getting detailed and use fractional densities for heavier ions, it would not change the results enough to matter.**).

If we compare the solar wind now, we have $n_{p} \sim 10^{7}$ m<sup>-3</sup> and $T_{p}$ ~ 10 eV [e.g., Wilson et al., 2018].  I realize that the solar wind is not characteristic of the cold [interstellar medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium) (ISM) to which the evolution discussed implies, but it will not matter as you will see.

So if we take the old and current universe values we find that:
$$
\nu_{old} \sim 10^{31}  \\
\nu_{new} \sim 10^{8}
$$
or a decrease of ~23 orders of magnitude.

Suppose we use ISM averages for the warm ionized medium (i.e., $n_{p}$ ~ 0.2–0.5 cm<sup>-3</sup> and $T_{p}$ ~ 8000 K ~ 0.7 eV), again assuming only protons, then we have $\nu_{new} \sim 10^{5}$, which is again much smaller than the early universe value.

**Note:**  I see that I said things backwards in my original comment.  I should have said, as the thermal speed decreases, the collision rate will increase for constant density.

> In online PDF's I noticed that they take it as a constant along with masses during analysis. How?

I am not sure why the speeds used to estimate Coulomb collision rates would be considered constant over the age of the universe because that is not consistent with our current understanding.

## **References**

- Wilson, L.B., III, et al., "The Statistical Properties of Solar Wind Temperature Parameters Near 1 au," *Astrophys. J. Suppl.* **236**(2), pp. 41, doi:10.3847/1538-4365/aab71c, 2018.